# ASP.NET WebApi - two possible JSON "return" types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

**A little intro**

Hello, I'm developing a WebApi Rest Service and currently I'm working on an endpoint which returns different dictionaries (arrays of entities, don't confuse with `Dictionary` data type) in JSON format. Dictionaries can be retrieved by name: `/dictionaries/:dictName`. The problem is that items kept in dictionaries can be of two types:

*First type of entities*

```
class Item {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*Second type of entities* - extended item

```
class ExtendedItem : Item {
    public string AdditionalProperty { get; set; } // Let's name it this way just for example
}
```

---

**The problem**

I'd like to avoid sending `AdditionalProperty` for dictionaries which don't need it.

---

**Current solution**

I've developed a simple method in ApiController:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDict(string name)
{
    try
    {
        object outDict = null;

        switch(name) {
            case "simpleDict":
                IList<Item> simpleDict = _dataLayer.GetSimpleDict();
                // ...
                outDict = simpleDict;
                break;
            case "extDict":
                IList<ExtendedItem> extDict = _dataLayer.GetExtDict();
                // ...
                outDict = extDict;
                break;

            // ... and a few more dictionaries
        }

        SomeLogger.SomeLogging(name, outDict);
        return Ok(outDict);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // Just returning error
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

---

**Conclusion and questions**

Although I managed to find a solution for the problem, I'm not fully satisfied with it. Personally, I'd like to find a simple way to avoid using `object` data type, however couldn't figure any. And now come the questions:

1. What would be a better programmatic way of implementing such solution? For me *better* means solution without using the `object` type. Is there any easy way to restrict IList to contain either Item or ExtendedItem and no other types?
2. Or maybe I should completely change the approach to the problem?
3. Or... Maybe this approach is correct and I'm a bit oversensitive? ;-)

I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: What happens if you make `outDict` of type `IEnumerable<Item>`? You should be able to assign directly of any derived type.

Comment: I cannot believe it was as simple as that! Works like a charm. If you can, add an answer so I can accept it. And thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your `outDict` variable as a collection instead of `object`, then you'll be able to assign directly.

```
IEnumerable<Base> outDict = null;

switch(name) {
    case "simpleDict":
        IList<Item> simpleDict = _dataLayer.GetSimpleDict();
        // ...
        outDict = simpleDict;
        break;
    case "extDict":
        IList<ExtendedItem> extDict = _dataLayer.GetExtDict();
        // ...
        outDict = extDict;
        break;

    // ... and a few more dictionaries
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Your answer in the comment was correct and works like a charm. I've just made a little mistake and realized it just after replying your comment. Although this one seems really nice too, I'll stick to the first one :-) Thanks!

Comment: I've fixed my answer to match my comment. The way I had it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Interface` to free up the implementation for ExtendedItem. Using Object for API return can be useful if you need Type dynamic to process things differently before sending back the callback response.

```
interface Item {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class SimpleItem : Item {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class ComplicateItem: Item {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the api controller,

```
    Item outDict;

    switch(name) {
        case "simpleDict":
            var simpleDict = _dataLayer.GetSimpleDict();
            // ...
            outDict = simpleDict;
            break;
        case "extDict":
            var extDict = _dataLayer.GetExtDict();
            // ...
            outDict = extDict;
            break;

        // ... and a few more dictionaries
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but in my case the objects `simpleDict` and `extDict` are lists of objects, not simple objects. Moreover, I've already got satisfying answers in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return in the switch statement as well:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDict(string name)
{
    try
    {
        switch(name) {
            case "simpleDict":
               return Ok(_dataLayer.GetSimpleDict());
            case "extDict":
               return Ok(_dataLayer.GetExtDict());
        }

        SomeLogger.SomeLogging(name, outDict);
        return Ok(new List<Item>());
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // Just returning error
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be ok in a simple case, but in my code I'd be forced to execute data logging and a few other instructions repeatedly for each block of the switch. That's why I created a local variable - to do it once at the end and then return data to client.